# Using Ok outside of ApiController, inside ActionFilter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, action-filter, exceptionfilterattribute

I'm using an action filter for handling exceptions inside my `ApiController` methods.

My methods return results as JSON using `return Ok(object)` however when I want to handle exceptions in my Action Filter for handling exception of my ApiController methods, it does not have access to `Ok` method to serialize objects as JSON since it is a protected method inside `ApiController`.
Here is a sample of my action filter:

```
public class WebServiceExceptionFilter : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        Exception exception = filterContext.Exception;
        if (exception is DbEntityValidationException)
        {
            List<string> errorMessageList = generateValidationErrorMessageList((DbEntityValidationException)e);
            string detailedError = String.Join(" ; ", errorMessageList);
            filterContext.Result = Ok(new WebServiceResult(ErrorCodes.ERROR_CODE_MINUS_3002_DB_VALIDATION, detailedError)); 
            //---------------------^^ Ok is not available ------
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Ok because that is a ControllerBase Object and you can't use Controller as a base class for your ActionFilter. What you can do is set the status code of your filterContext.HttpContext like this:

```
filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = exception.StatusCode;
```

or use a custom statusCode (like 500) instead of exception.StatusCode

Answer (score 0):

According to the source code of [ControllerBase](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ControllerBase.cs) returning `Ok` result from `Controller` is simply returning `OkObjectResult` instance.

```
[NonAction]
public virtual OkObjectResult Ok([ActionResultObjectValue] object value)
    => new OkObjectResult(value);
```

So you can set it directly to `filterContext.Result`

```
var result = new WebServiceResult(ErrorCodes.ERROR_CODE_MINUS_3002_DB_VALIDATION, detailedError);
filterContext.Result = new OkObjectResult(result);
```